# Using mongodb collection as stream in Flutter Streambuilder

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I'm using mongoDb, node and express for backend, and flutter for frontend. I want to stream one of my mongo collection as live data in my app, so decided to use Socket.io in backend, my question is can i convert mongoDb collection into Stream so i can use it in StreamBuilder widget (like firestore snapshot).